# Get return value for template lambda parameter, how to simplify code?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, return, decltype, result-of

This is my trick:

```
template<typename F, typename TArg>
auto get_return_value(F * f = NULL, TArg * arg = NULL)
     -> decltype((*f)(*arg));
```

Example of using:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
decltype(get_return_value<F,T>()) applyFtoT(F f, T t)
{
    return f(t);
}
```

In case F is lambda:

```
int b = applyFtoT([](int a){return a*2}, 10);
// b == 20
```

Function get_return_value looks ugly i think... How to simplify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you could eliminate the need for `get_return_value` by changing the declaration of `applyFtoT` like so:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
auto applyFtoT(F f, T t) -> decltype(f(t))
{
   return f(t);
}
```

Comment: And what if F if class template parameter, not a function... I cant use field f...

Comment: I would like to kill get_return_type here: [link](http://code.google.com/p/boolinq/source/browse/boolinq/SelectRange.h)

Comment: That's a bit more difficult. I don't see a cleaner solution than what you already have.